# Spring OAuth2 restrict user to authenticate via a client

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0

I am implementing a Spring OAuth2 application where I have different clients using a resource.

The clients are mobile applications, so I use the Resource Owner Password Flow.

There are 2 roles in my application: normal users and managers. Respectively there are 2 clients, one for the normal users and one for managers.

I don't want to apply logic on the mobile applications (clients) to check if the user has the necessary roles to access the application. As I understood the tokens should be opaque to the client.

I already restrict the resources with user roles, but I don't want the auth server to provide the client with an access code when the user is not supposed to use that client.

How can I restrict authorization for some users on some clients?

Thanks in advance!

oauth config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_MANAGER') and hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')");
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("demo").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("manager").password("password").roles("MANAGER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("manager-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_MANAGER")
                .scopes("trust")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you use to connect to your Oauth server? Just specify grant type when requesting token, token wont be granted if grant type of the client trying to authorize does not match the one that is specified for the client on the Oauth server.  No authorization will be completed when grant types dont match.

Comment: I use grant type password. The problem is not about authorizing clients. I just need to restrict users that don't have a specific role from connecting to a client

Comment: what about setting `.authorities("ROLE")` on your `ClientDetailsServiceBuilder` if you showed your oauth configuration it could be little easier

Comment: Hi, thx for your interest in the question. I edited the question with the oauth config.

Comment: I know this request from the auth server is outside of the scope of oauth2 specifications. I think if I want to implement this I need to override [ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java).getOAuth2Authentication in the framework. But that class is not a spring managed bean.

Comment: As a work around, I have implemented a check in the log in function of the client, if the user can access a default endpoint of the resource server. It's not beautiful but it works...